# Cross browser event type detection

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom, detection

In JQuery, you can just do:

```
$("#123").bind("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll MozMousePixelScroll", function(e) {
    // Code here
}, false)
```

How do you detect which one of "mousewheel", "DOMMouseScroll" and "MozMousePixelScroll", if you don't use JQuery?

```
document.getElementById("123").addEventListener(?????, function(e) {
    // Code here
}, false)
```

Comment: but I have multiple events, I mean I want it in the form addEventListener

Comment: use "scroll" on your addEventListener

Comment: will that work for cross browser then?

Comment: For multiple event types, you will need to call `addEventListener` multiple times.

Comment: Can't you detect in anyway which one that should be used, and then just save it in a variable and then only have 1 "ddEventListener"?